# How can i add expansion tile widgets inside GridView.builder() in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I was working on grid views and got stuck when trying to insert expansion tiles inside the grid view.The problem that i am facing is,  when tring to expand the tile, i am getting an overflow error. Is there any way to use expansion tile inside grid view in such a way that when one of the tiles is expanded, the other tiles moves down without causing any overflow error ?

Here's my code snippet :

```
 Expanded(
             child: GridView.builder(
                                itemCount: 21,
                                physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                                gridDelegate:
                                    SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                  crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                                  mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                                  childAspectRatio: (1 / 0.46),
                                  crossAxisCount:
                                      (MediaQuery.of(context).orientation ==
                                              Orientation.landscape)
                                          ? 4
                                          : 1,
                                ),
                                itemBuilder:
                                    (BuildContext context, int index) => Card(
                                  elevation: 6.0,
                                  child: ClipRRect(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                    child: ExpansionTile(
                                      // collapsedBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                      // backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                      trailing: FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
                                        image:
                                            'https://picsum.photos/250?image=123',
                                        placeholder: kTransparentImage,
                                      ),
                                      title: Container(
                                        child: Text(
                                          'Pencil Pen Test Long String Again Test Long String',
                                        ),
                                      ),

                                      subtitle: Padding(
                                        padding:
                                            const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
                                        child: Text(
                                          '\u{20B9} $myAmount',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        Padding(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                          child: Column(
                                            crossAxisAlignment:
                                                CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                            children: <Widget>[
                                              Align(
                                                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                                child: Text('Price 1 :' +
                                                    ' \u{20B9} $myAmount'),
                                              ),
                                              Align(
                                                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                                child: Text('Price 2 :' +
                                                    ' \u{20B9} $myAmount'),
                                              ),
                                              Align(
                                                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                                child: Text('Price 3 :' +
                                                    ' \u{20B9} $myAmount'),
                                              ),
                                              SizedBox(
                                                height: 6.0,
                                              ),
                                              Column(
                                                children: [
                                                  Container(
                                                    padding:
                                                        EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                                                    child: Align(
                                                      alignment:
                                                          Alignment.centerLeft,
                                                      child: Text(
                                                        'TAGS',
                                                        style: TextStyle(
                                                          color: Colors.white,
                                                          decoration:
                                                              TextDecoration
                                                                  .underline,
                                                        ),
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                  Row(
                                                    children: [
                                                      Expanded(
                                                        child: InputChip(
                                                          onDeleted: () {},
                                                          onPressed: () {},
                                                          label: Text('Chip a'),
                                                          avatar: Icon(
                                                              Icons.ac_unit),
                                                        ),
                                                      ),
                                                      Expanded(
                                                        child: InputChip(
                                                          onDeleted: () {},
                                                          onPressed: () {},
                                                          label: Text('Chip b'),
                                                          avatar: Icon(Icons
                                                              .e_mobiledata),
                                                        ),
                                                      ),
                                                      Expanded(
                                                        child: InputChip(
                                                          onDeleted: () {},
                                                          onPressed: () {},
                                                          label: Text('Chip c'),
                                                          avatar: Icon(Icons
                                                              .format_align_justify_outlined),
                                                        ),
                                                      ),
                                                    ],
                                                  ),
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                              Divider(),
                                              Row(
                                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                                    MainAxisAlignment
                                                        .spaceBetween,
                                                children: <Widget>[
                                                  Row(
                                                    children: [
                                                      Text(
                                                        'In Hand : ',
                                                        style: TextStyle(
                                                          fontWeight:
                                                              FontWeight.bold,
                                                          color:
                                                              Theme.of(context)
                                                                  .colorScheme
                                                                  .secondary,
                                                        ),
                                                      ),
                                                    ],
                                                  ),
                                                  Row(
                                                    children: [
                                                      IconButton(
                                                        onPressed: () {
                                                          displayBottomSheetAddInventory(
                                                              context);
                                                        },
                                                        icon: Icon(
                                                            Icons.add_circle),
                                                      ),
                                                      IconButton(
                                                        onPressed: () {
                                                          displayBottomSheetSubtractInventory(
                                                              context);
                                                        },
                                                        icon: Icon(Icons
                                                            .remove_circle),
                                                      ),
                                                      IconButton(
                                                        onPressed: () {
                                                          displayBottomSheetEditInventory(
                                                              context);
                                                        },
                                                        icon: Icon(
                                                          Icons.edit,
                                                        ),
                                                      ),
                                                    ],
                                                  ),
                                                ],
                                              )
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
```

This is what i'm getting:

[image]

And this is want i want : (The other tiles should be below this tile and readjust when collapsed.)

[image]

Can anyone help ?

Comment: I'm encountering a similar issue at the moment, my only suggestion is using a ListView.Builder() instead. You'll need to comment out the gridDelegate parameter. If you found a solution please let me know.

Comment: Having the same issue. Did you find out any solution for that?